# composer installation from behind proxy server

Tags: php, proxy, composer-php, packagist

I'm trying to run `composer update` on windows 10 behind a proxy server, it gives me an error.
[image]

and I set http proxy using below command

```
SET HTTP_PROXY="http://192.168.1.6:808"
SET HTTPS_PROXY="http://192.168.1.6:808"
```

this also return same error.

Comment: Please copy/paste the error here instead of posting a screenshot.

Answer (score 6):

Here are the key points to make Composer work behind a proxy (works on Windows, didn't try on Linux):

**1) URL encode your password (for special characters)**

You can do that easily with the PHP command line, for example:

Input:

```
php -r "echo urlencode('P*a/$$/w!0%r$d');"
```

Output:

```
P%2Aa%2F%24%24%2Fw%210%25r%24d
```

Use the generated value to set the HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY env variables.

**2) Remove the quotes around the HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY env variables**

From:

```
SET HTTP_PROXY="http://username:password@hostname:port"
SET HTTPS_PROXY="http://username:password@hostname:port"
```

To:

```
SET HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@hostname:port
SET HTTPS_PROXY=http://username:password@hostname:port
```

Composer **WON'T WORK** with quotes, it uses the PHP core function "parse_url" to parse the variable:

With quotes:

```
php -r "print_r(parse_url('\"http://username:password@proxy:8080\"'));"

Array
(
    [path] => "http://username:password@proxy:8080"
)
```

Without quotes:

```
php -r "print_r(parse_url('http://username:password@proxy:8080'));"

Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => proxy
    [port] => 8080
    [user] => username
    [pass] => password
)
```

**3) Make sure the certificate authority file or path is correctly set for HTTPS connections**

Composer will use the **first readable** file or path in the following order:

- Env variables:

  ```
  SSL_CERT_FILE
  SSL_CERT_DIR
  ```
- php.ini:

  ```
  openssl.cafile
  openssl.capath
  ```
- Files:

  ```
      /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
      /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
      /etc/ssl/ca-bundle.pem
      /usr/local/share/certs/ca-root-nss.crt
      /usr/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
      /opt/local/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt
      /usr/local/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt
      /usr/share/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
      /etc/ssl/cert.pem
      /usr/local/etc/ssl/cert.pem
      /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem
  ```
- Non-empty folder:

  ```
      /etc/pki/tls/certs/
      /etc/ssl/certs/
      /etc/ssl/
      /usr/local/share/certs/
      /usr/ssl/certs/
      /opt/local/share/curl/
      /usr/local/share/curl/
      /usr/share/ssl/certs/
      /etc/ssl/
      /usr/local/etc/ssl/
      /usr/local/etc/openssl/
  ```

If none of the above is valid, Composer will use its embedded file:

```
    composer.phar /vendor/composer/ca-bundle/res/cacert.pem
```

**4) If you experience the "certificate verify failed" error**

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
failed to open stream: Cannot connect to HTTPS server through proxy
```

This means that the used CA file or path does not contains the required certificates.

You may then:

- extract the default file from composer.phar:

  ```
  php -r "(new Phar('composer.phar'))->extractTo('/tmp/cacert/', 'vendor/composer/ca-bundle/res/cacert.pem');"
  ```
- then add the required certificates (e.g. your company proxy certificates) to the end of the file
- and force this file in php.ini

  ```
  [openssl]
  ; The location of a Certificate Authority (CA) file on the local filesystem
  ; to use when verifying the identity of SSL/TLS peers. Most users should
  ; not specify a value for this directive as PHP will attempt to use the
  ; OS-managed cert stores in its absence. If specified, this value may     still
  ; be overridden on a per-stream basis via the "cafile" SSL stream context
  ; option.
  openssl.cafile=/tmp/cacert/vendor/composer/ca-bundle/res/cacert.pem
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it needs authentication too? Try this if so:

`SET HTTP_PROXY="http://username:password@hostname:port"
 SET HTTPS_PROXY="http://username:password@hostname:port"`

Answer (score 0):

encode your password then use

```
SET HTTP_PROXY="http://username:encodedPassword@hostname:port"
SET HTTPS_PROXY="http://username:encodedPassword@hostname:port"
```

Comment: This answer gives no additional value compared to the one given by Thomas Guillier

Answer (score 0):

The best way if it fails to work is to enter this command

```
    SET HTTP_PROXY=0
    SET HTTPS_PROXY=0
```

This will empty the proxy then you can now use `composer.install`